# please help with this installation error

Tags: magento2

I have installed Magento 2.3.0 from site ground, when clicking the link to my website i get this:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) in /home/motiveat/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Filesystem/Directory/Write.php on line 35

what do i do?, what have i done wrong? i am not tech savvy and just want to build my website

thanks

Comment: Please check the php version? If lower then update it!

Answer (score 0):

Php requirment form magento 2.3.0 is 7.1.3+ or 7.2.x . please check your php version and upgrade php version.

for more details refer https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html

Comment: I have scrolled down to PHP version manager and changed it to  PHP 7.2.13 but it is still stating error message? am i doing it wrong

Answer (score 0):

In my case the error still occurred after the accepted fix. Solution was to update PHP version from 7.0 to 7.2.